# masscan not showing open ports

Tags: networking, port, nmap

I scan an IP with nmap and a port is open, but when I scan with masscan it shows found=0.

EDIT: Tried nmap with those same forced options and it did it's job as opposed to masscan.

```
D:\Nmap\nmap -p445 x.x.x.x

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-02 20:52 FLE Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x
Host is up (0.063s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.16 seconds




D:\masscan\masscan x.x.x.x -p445
D:\masscan\masscan x.x.x.x -p445 --banners

Starting masscan 1.0.3 () at 2017-08-02 17:53:55 GMT (compi led for www.Proxy-Base.Org members)
 -- forced options: -sS -Pn -n --randomize-hosts -v --send-eth
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan
Scanning 1 hosts [1 port/host]
```

So, why is masscan not detecting that and how to fix it? I've been scaning a range that has many servers with that port open as I know from nmap and masscan doesn't pick up on any, while working fine with same switches and settings when scanning for port 80.

I imagine the service microsoft-ds behaves differently and is something about the type of scan being performed - SYN Stealth Scan...

Edit:

Found a trace option in the docs:

```
D:\masscan>D:\masscan\masscan x.x.x.x -p445 --show open,closed --packet-trace
SENT (0.0547) ARP  192.168.1.203         > 192.168.1.1           request

Starting masscan 1.0.3 () at 2017-08-02 19:10:15 GMT (compiled for www.Proxy-Base.Org members)
 -- forced options: -sS -Pn -n --randomize-hosts -v --send-eth
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan
Scanning 1 hosts [1 port/host]
SENT (0.2618) TCP  192.168.1.203:41015   > x.x.x.x:445      SYN
```

Comment: You may want to edit and make your question a bit more clear.  In its current form, we can only assume what you are asking.

Comment: Hope this makes it clear...